# Service like rootScope that emits events

Tags: angularjs

Someone probably asked this question, yet I couldn't find a satisfiable answer. So I'm wondering if it's possible to have a service that would emit and broadcast events - same way as `$rootScope` does. Something like:

```
app.controller 'myController', (myService)->
    myService.$on 'pokeEvent', -> 
      console.log "I've been poked"
```

Of course one can always use rootScope but I'm curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Angular's event system is tied to scopes: the [`$emit`, `$broadcast` and `$on` methods exist on the `Scope` prototype](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L165). Services, by default, don't associate with any particular scope so you will need to inject $rootScope to send/listen for events.

Comment: But there's a way to emulate a behavior similar to how rootScope works, right? The question is - would it be right to do so and if that worth the effort and maybe it's better just to use rootScope? I'm just not very comfortable pushing too many things through the rootScope

Comment: @Agzam you could build your own event system, or use one of the event libraries out there, but is it really providing any value over and above what Angular already provides? Keep in mind that anything custom or external needs play nice with Angular (with $digest cycles, for example), so it's not likely to be a simple plug-and-play.